# wrong value when storing big float value

Tags: mysql, mariadb, floating-point

i got a weird problem using mariadb.

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb;
USE testdb;
CREATE TABLE testing (afloat FLOAT NULL);
INSERT INTO testing VALUES(123456789.0);
SELECT * FROM testing;
```

But instead of returning `123456789` it returns `123457000`.

I'm aware of the precision with floating numbers in IEEE 754 but even considering this the actual value stored is `123456792`.

I came across this documentation but I am not that experienced with the ISO C standard.
[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/floating-point-types.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/floating-point-types.html#:%7E:text=Since%20MySQL%20uses%20the%20machine,for%20binary%20floating%2Dpoint%20arithmetic.&text=However%2C%20we%20can%20not%20rely,every%20system%20uses%20this%20representation)

Can somebody explain why mariadb is not storing the expected value please?

*PS: I know the problem could be solved using a double but I want to understand why it is not working with a float.*

Comment: Try `SELECT format(afloat, 0) as afloat from testing ;`

Comment: or `select round(afloat, 0) as afloat from testing ;`

Comment: thanks of course this will work but it doesn't explain the actual reason why the float is interpreted as 123457000 - it has to be something with how the bytes are interpreted

Comment: The float is displayed with accuracy of 6 digits because anything after that is garbage.

Comment: is this behaviour documented somewhere in the mysql/mariadb documentation?

Comment: Not sure. I looked around but couldn't find anything related. You could send a bug/question to MySQL or MariaDB and the devs will surely reply. For MariaDB, this is where you can do it: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-community-bug-reporting/

Answer (score 2):

> why the float is interpreted as 123457000

The *outout formatting* process did that.  (Since you have not specified what tool was used to do the `SELECT`, I cannot address it specifically.)

Any output process has to decide what to do with imprecise data.

1. How many decimal places should it show for `SELECT 1/3;`?
2. Since `FLOAT` has only about 6-7 significant digits, why bother showing more than that?  (`DOUBLE`: 16)
3. Should the output be designed so that reading the string back in will get the same binary value?

From this, I see that your example violates #3:

```
    hex           float        check
    4ceb79a3 --> 123456792 --> 4ceb79a3
    4ceb79bd --> 123457000 --> 4ceb79bd - off by 26 ULPs
```

From these, I see that the output should have used 8 digits to satisfy #3:

```
    4ceb79a4 --> 123456800 --> 4ceb79a4 - 7 digits is not quite close enough (1 ULP)
```

Feel free to file a bug report *against the specific product in question*.  Provide the link here and I will probably add my 2-cents worth.

"why mariadb is not storing the expected value" -- Try `SELECT 1.0*flt FROM ...` to see what was stored.  That should provide the value displayed as `DOUBLE`.  I claim the problem is with the display, not the storage.

Comment: I'm using the good old mysql cli - I also think it's the way the value is read/displayed. When changing the data type to double **after** inserting the correct value is displayed.

Comment: > Since FLOAT has only about 6-7 significant digits...

can you provide a documentation? This was what I was looking for before I created this post but I couldn't find much

Comment: Since virtually every computer and language uses IEEE 754, the information about it is assumed without necessarily stating it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 is a starting point.  (However, that document is a bit overwhelming.)